Examples of noncomplete, simply connected Riemannian manifolds with nonpositive sectional curvature
I will be giving a talk on the Cartan-Hadamard theorem next week (in the context of a learning/reading group), which states (in the form I will be presenting) that a complete simply connected Riemannian manifold $M^n$ with nonpositive sectional curvature is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am trying to come up with examples that show each of the hypotheses are required.

The 2-sphere is complete and simply connected, but does not admit a metric with nonpositive sectional curvature.
The flat torus is complete and has nonpositive sectional curvature, but is not simply connected.

I can't seem to come up with an example where we don't have completeness, but do have all the other assumptions. Some ideas that have floated around in my head involve removing points from complete manifolds, such as:

A once-punctured 2-sphere (with the round metric). However, this is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.
A twice-punctured 2-sphere (with the round metric). However, this is not simply connected.

Another problem with these examples is that the metric I'm choosing has positive sectional curvature.
It's clear that completeness is required (how would we get a global result otherwise?), but I can't seem to come up with an example.

In summary, I am trying to come up with an example of a (connected) Riemannian manifold $M^n$ that:

is simply connected;
has nonpositive sectional curvature;
is not complete;
is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Preferably, I would like an intuitive/easy to explain example, as the audience will not be experts in geometry. I am also not an expert in geometry myself (as evidenced by this question).

Remove a ball from hyperbolic $3$-space.

Actually, it suffices to remove a point.

A twice punctured sphere works just fine if the dimension of that sphere is $n \ge 3$, because in that case it is indeed simply connected but still not homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

In dimension 2, you have to deal with the fact that every simply connected surface is homeomorphic to either $\mathbb R^2$ or $S^2$.

@LeeMosher, would such manifolds need to have positive sectional curvature somewhere?

@Deane, I think this works well, thanks! My elementary explanation is: it's clear that hyperbolic 3-space with a point removed (clearly nonpositive sectional curvature) is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}$, which is simply connected. From this, it is also clear that it is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. Does this sound right?

All spheres in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are contractible, while not all spheres in  $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}$ are contractible. From this they are not diffeomorphic.

@user3257842, yes this completes the argument, thanks. In particular, $S^2\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3\setminus{0}$ is not contractible.
